# Spring Cloud Eureka/Spring Cloud Config integration

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix

Can Spring Cloud Eureka get some of its properties from Spring Cloud Config with our microservices utilizing Discovery First Bootstrap? So, our Spring Cloud Config microservices start up and attempt to register with our Spring Cloud Eureka microservices so they can be discovered, while Spring Cloud Eureka microservices start up and attempt to get some of their configuration properties from the Spring Cloud Config microservices. This is the ideal scenario I'm trying to implement, but it makes sense to me that this would result in both sets of microservices waiting on each other, resulting in a deadlocked state. It's important to note that we have three Spring Cloud Eureka instances running as peers, giving us an HA configuration, as well as three Spring Cloud Config instances. With all `eureka.*` properties in the Spring Cloud Eureka bootstrap.yml, everything starts fine, and the peers are able to replicate with each other. However, as soon as I configure Spring Cloud Eureka to get its properties from Spring Cloud Config, each instance fails to connect to its peers.

So, my main question is whether or not this configuration even makes sense, and if so, where is the documentation that covers such a configuration?

Comment: Something has to be known upfront. Either config server address, or in discovery first bootstrap, eureka.

Comment: Eureka in the discovery first bootstrap can't look up config server from itself